# How to retrive central_logger's info in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I am using central_logger(0.3.3) gem for my rails app.

I follow each instruction as per documentation https://github.com/customink/central_logger.

record inserted successfully. But I want to fetch records of central_logger to show analysis 
in my app is there any way?

please help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the db and its records as per the documentation

```
db = Rails.logger.mongo_connection  #specifies db, NO Need to change anything use as is

collection = db[Rails.logger.mongo_collection_name] #specifies mongo collection, NO Need to change anything use as is.

cursor = collection.find(:action => 'show') #get all central_logger records with action show 

cursor.each do |obj|
  obj ## A single mongo  record object
end
```

Works for me...!